Can not fetch data from server site after deploying it on vercel
I am zami. Recently I am having problem with a project while fetching data from the server site in the client site. I can easily fetch data in client site when the server site is on localhost but after i deployed the server site on vercel it gives me some errors like cors-policy. the cors middleware is given and i also tried credentials true method. But it did not work. the vercel site link worked but client site can not fetch the data of it and shows cors policy issue. however, using the localhost link of the server site i can easily fetch the data in the client site.
It the problem related to my vercel acciount or projects settings?
i have written many code but it did not work.The link of the backend server deployed by vercel is also good and it worked but the main problem is when i fetch data. And the link given by vercel does not open on firefox it says that i have login tovercel first via firefox as i dont use firefox much it didnot login there.
if you have any opinion about how can i solve this problem please tell me.
i have tried credentials: true in the backend and frontend code to solve this but it did not work

I think we need more context. This could be related to a few things and we'd have to have a better understanding of what data you're trying to fetch, what 3rd party service this data might be stored at (cloud database, sanity.io, etc) to determine if the issue is in your code or possibly a third-party that needs to have your live domain whitelisted.
